I'm trying to represent a Tree-like data structure, but running into OutOfMemoryError. Improvements?
Let me start by saying that I already found a solution to my problem, but I had to cut corners in a way that I didn't like. So, I am asking the larger community to understand the CORRECT way to do this.
I need to represent a Tree-like data structure that is exactly 4 levels deep. Here is a rough outline of what it looks like.
ROOT ------ A1 ---- B1 ---- C1 -- D1
|           |       |------ C2 -- D2
|           |       |------ C3 -- D3
|           |
|           |------ B2 ---- C4 -- D4
|                   |------ C5 -- D5
|                   |------ C6 -- D6
|           
|---------- A2 ---- B1 ---- C7 -- D7
            |       |------ C8 -- D8
            |       |------ C9 -- D9
            |
            |------ B2 ---- C10 -- D10
                    |------ C11 -- D11
                    |------ C12 -- D12

Imagine this tree, but millions of elements at the C level. As is likely no surprise, I ran into an OutOfMemoryError trying to represent this.
For now, I am going to intentionally leave out RAM specifics because I am not trying to know whether or not this is possible for my specific use case.
No, for now, I simply want to know what would be the idiomatic way to represent a large amount of data in a tree-like structure like this, while being mindful of RAM usage.
Here is the attempt that I did that caused an OutOfMemoryError.
Map<A, Map<B, Map<C, D>>> myTree;

As you can see, I chose not to represent the ROOT, since it is a single element, and thus, easily recreated where needed.
I also considered making my own tree-like data structure, but decided against it for fear of "recreating a map, but badly". I was about to do it anyways, but i found my own workaround that dealt with the problem for me.
But I wanted to ask, is there a better way to do this that I am missing? What is the proper way to model a tree-like data structure while minimizing RAM usage?

I have read this twice but cannot see what you have done. Could you make it clearer so that people have all the context?

Algorithms and data structures are inseparable. The most compact data structure you have available in Java is an array, but your necessary operations on these trees might make this infeasible. Using a HashMap for each node's children sounds very sensible if you primarily need access by path/ID (e.g. root → A2 → B3 → C8). Millions of elements isn't necessarily a lot, that's probably still much less than 1GB for the entire tree.

@MartinKochanski I am unable to provide much more context because this is related to my work, and I have strict requirements on what I am and am not allowed to say. All I am trying to do is model a tree 4 levels deep, and I want to find the data structure that does this while minimizing the amount of RAM being used. That's it. I wanted to know what most Java developers would reach for given those requirements.

@amon That is a very good point. Unfortunately, the option that ran into an OutOfMemoryError was in fact the HashMap solution that you have just suggested.

If you need compact memory representation above all else, use a "structure of arrays" approach instead of classes. Nodes are represented as an index into these arrays, not as a pointer. You don't need a map to hold children, you just need a minimum and maximum index. However, traversing this representation is more difficult (e.g. finding a node might require a linear search), and mutating the object graph is near-impossible (you cannot move stuff around without invalidating indexes). This feels more like C than like Java, but until Project Valhalla ships there is no good alternative.

Come on, you need to tell us a little bit more. I am sure that's possible without disclosing anything confidential. What about the objects at the C level? How large and complex are they? Maybe there is a more compact representation? Then: what kind of processing do you have in mind for the tree - does the processing need the whole tree in memory at once, or may it be sufficient to load the tree only partially on-demand?

... and your Map<A, Map<B, C>>  makes no sense to me. Shouldn't it be  Map<A, Map<B, C[]>[]> or a Map<A, ArrayList<Map<B, ArrayList<C>>>>  ?

@DocBrown Yes, I made a mistake in representing the Map. Truthfully, there's actually more to this problem than I let on, so I tried to simplify it down and failed to do so correctly. I will edit my post.

As for C (which is now D, see my post), assume that it is a fairly small object. <5 fields, and all of them are primitives. And the whole tree needs to be in memory.

You need a data structure that meets your performance requirements including query, update (ingestion), uptime/availability, and cost.  The more stringent your requirements, the harder it will be without giving up on one, e.g. cost as your basic option. to scale out to use multiple servers, higher performance servers, buy/rent more memory, etc, and hire more programmers to make a distributed system work seamlessly..

@ErikEidt Ty for your response. Yes, I agree, this is very much a "3 switches, pick 2" problem. Let's say that I am willing to sacrifice time of insertion and just wanted to maximize for space. What would you approach with?

Should A2 contain B3/4 in this example instead of B1/2? This is what you did for C, but it's notably different for B.

Also, big picture, what is it you're trying to achieve here? Are you bulk processing an import file? Are you trying to query and display a large data set? Are you trying to load a bunch of data to perform some aggregate calculation on them? ... Different use cases have different solutions. While they'll always boil down to "batch it", I suspect you'll want a more bespoke answer than those two words.

I voted to close, but not for the shown reason. My vote was "needs details or clarity", and the final edit did not answer any of my questions (it actually introduced more questions). I will be happy to cast a reopen vote when we get a decent explanation of the things raised here in the comments.

... There was time enough to clarify things, but the OP apparently shows no interest in this question any more. Voting to delete.

Sorry, I was out of town and I just got back. I can start cleaning this up tomorrow or tonight. @DocBrown

@DocBrown Sorry, got home and have to juggle work emergencies, so I have not, and will not (for a while) have time to fix this. I know this site has its rules and standards. If it's easier, just go ahead and delete this question, and I can ask a new one when I get the time, with all the corrections from this one included.

By using Java, you are giving up on the direct control and access to memory and allowing the language runtime to make assumptions for you.  I'm assuming that you have done the calculations and are confident that the total volume of data that you are wanting to store in memory should fit within your environment's ram, so here are a few of my ideas that you can consider.

String data - if you are storing lots of text value data, and these values can be represented by ASCII values, then explicitly storing the values as ascii encoded strings in an 8 bit byte array is likely to half your memory consumption.
Using a hashmap to store your data will make its access quick, but have you considered how the hashmap adds extra data when you insert each value?  Its possible that the insert / add key method causes the creation of a replacement data structure to hold the set of values, leaving the previous data in garbage collection, waiting for GC recycling to occur.
Closely related to the previous point, memory fragmentation can leave you in a state where you have a total amount of free memory, but all of the free blocks are too small for your current allocation. If there is not a continuous block of free memory large enough for the java language runtime to assign, then it will throw an out of memory error.

I would suggest reading carefully how the java garbage collection (GC) behaves within your specific environment, see if there is any diagnostic calls you can make to understand the GC state as you load the data into memory, and understand exactly which problem you are running into.
The next issue that I can think of is whether your data volume is being multiplied by lots of copies of your key and value objects everywhere.  I'm thinking that if your keys A, B and C are themselves objects with properties, rather than a short string or a number - and that this is combined with lots of repetition:
e.g.  Key A has 1000 possible object instances, Key B has 1000 possible object instances and Key C has 1000 possible object instances. Then consider if each value in the Key A level map was a map of most of the key B values, and the map implementation stores a copy of the key when each key/value is added, then you will get 1000 copies of each B key, and a million copies of each C key.
That said, this is all semi educated guesswork - because of the security restrictions that you are working under.

Thanks for the information. I am INCREDIBLY surprised to hear about Point 3. That's a simple defragmentation problem. Is that something that could truly trip up Java? And to make sure I understand point 1, you are telling me to store the data as a literal byte[]? If so, I am also surprised that Java doesn't do that under the hood for us already. Regardless, you have made it clear that I have a lot of assumptions that I need to validate. I will start digging now. Ty vm.

If you are an english speaker, 8 bit strings make sense. However, most of the world use character sets that are not ASCII.  think accents in the European languages, then chinese, arabic, indian character sets...   so most programing languages are working on the assumption that strings are unicode data encoded in utf16 or utf32 formats.

Touché. Kinda makes me wish for an AsciiString type, but alas. Thank you for all of the help. I have a very deep rabbit hole to travel down, and I will research it thoroughly. I likely won't be able to research enough in time to solve my current problem in a different way, but it will definitely guide me for future situations like this. Ty vm.

Think of Memory management in C / C++ where you manually allocate, reallocate and free memory. Keeping track of memory blocks that have been allocated and released is quite a challenge for the C memory manager.  When you add on a  managed language runtime where the language design results in code that makes and releases large numbers of objects under the covers, having a garbage collection process that does the low level freeing up the memory for its memory allocator to re-use, and identifying adjacent blocks that can be combined into larger blocks for later allocation is a challenge.

The OpenJDK String implementation already switches between different encodings internally. If you have an ASCII string, it will use its Latin-1 mode and only use 1 byte per char. See https://openjdk.org/jeps/254 which shipped in Java 9. Also, Java GCs are typically "compacting". Objects can be moved around after they're allocated, so the GC can close the holes. Fragmentation is more of an issue in long-running programs of languages where objects cannot be moved automatically, e.g. C++.

This sounds all like guesswork. The whole questions needs more details, and though it is clear the OP cannot diisclose internal information, I am sure they can give us more details in case they really want a useful answer for their question.
